# Should a reference table include numeric PK identity column value of 0?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

We have a table that contains the valid currency codes. We are choosing to use a numeric value as the primary key rather than a 3 char ISO Currency code, for example.

General consensus has concluded that this `CurrencyId` column should contain values that begin with zero. Since the US dollar is the primary currency for us, it claimed the first position with a value of 0.

My thought is that identity columns should not start at zero for the sole reason that some languages initialize numerics to zero and as a result the currency code may be unintentionally set to `USD` when really it was never assigned.

Am I all wet? I would prefer to assign a `CurrencyId` of 1 to `USD`.

Comment: Whatever you decide - just make sure to clearly document that somewhere, and get agreement from all developers and DBA's about the solution you picked! Also: if you do use `0` as a "real" value, you could still always pick e.g. `-1` as a placeholder value for "unknown" or "undefined" and set the columns referencing this table to use that value as a default.

Comment: @Chad - I agree with you. [This question has a similar sort of discussion about enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257409/should-an-enum-start-with-a-0-or-a-1/7257458#7257458)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual Id should not matter.  Having it start at 0 (or 1 for that matter) is completely arbitrary, as that number has no meaning to the user--it is only used by the system as a reference.  Whether it starts at 0 or 1 or 4,536,901 is not a critical design decision.

I think the issue that you raise is 100% valid; starting at 0 can cause side effects, some of which may end up as bugs that are subtle and difficult to track down.  Avoiding this **far** outweighs anyone's objection to an abitrary/aethstetic desire to start the numbering at zero.

Comment: +1, short version: just start at 1 you're not doing arrays in C