# C# Enum Flags HasFlag returns true but flag is not set

Tags: c#, enums, flags

I have this enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum SearchFormattings
{
    None = 0,
    ToLower = 1,
    NoPunctuationSerialNumber = 2
}
```

Then a variable is assigned and `HasFlag` is called:

```
var searchFormatting = SearchFormattings.ToLower | SearchFormattings.NoPunctuationSerialNumber;
```

I expect the following line to return `false` but it always returns true. What did I miss?

`searchFormatting.HasFlag(SearchFormattings.None)`

Comment: "None" is not a flag.  An ArgumentException would have been useful, but they did it by documenting "If the underlying value of flag is zero, the method returns true".

Comment: `anyNumber & 0 == 0` will always be true (should be equivalent as `anyNumber.HasFlag(0)`)

Comment: Also see:  [Why should I never use 0 in a flag enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811047/why-should-i-never-use-0-in-a-flag-enum)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=netframework-4.8 - "If the underlying value of flag is zero, the method returns true."

Comment: Yep that answers my question - ty